# copy mysql data to same the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to be able to copy all the rows that have no userid into the same table with a userid that equals 1.
this is the code that I have:(it doesnt work when I run it), it does display the items field and widget id field using echo. but it doesnt insert the data. any suggestions

```
    $sql=("SELECT * from options WHERE userid='' ");
    $resultat= mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultat))
  {
     $userid="1";
    echo $items.$widgetid."<br>";
      $widgetid = $row['widgetid'];
      $items = $row['items'];
       $stats = $row['stats'];
      $upd=("INSERT INTO options (userid, widgetid, items,stats)
VALUES ('$userid', '$widgetid','$items', '$stats')");
mysql_query($upd);
      }
```

Comment: If an insert fails, there's usually an error message associated with it. Without knowing what's really going on, my guess is `userid` is the PRIMARY KEY and can thus not occur twice.

Comment: PRIMARY          PRIMARY  23     id
widgetid  UNIQUE  23     widgetid. id is primary not userid. it doesnt return an error if it did I would fix it

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO options 
SELECT '1' AS userid, widgetid, items, stats 
FROM options
WHERE userid = ''
```

assuming this is the order of colums declared in your table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to update the rows where userid=''

```
update options 
set userid=1 
where userid='';


$upd=("INSERT INTO options (userid, widgetid, items,stats)
 select 1, widgetid, stats from options
 where userid='' ");
```

Comment: no I need copies of those. I am not trying to update the fields I need multiple ones so copies.I am very familiar with UPDATE and thats not what I am looking for.

Comment: Then try this query `insert into options(fields,userid) select fields,1 from options where userid='';`

Comment: I am not familiar with that syntax,its a loop and it contains variables as shown on the code above.

Comment: do I just put it between quotes ? how about the variables?

Comment: try this `$upd=("INSERT INTO options (userid, widgetid, items,stats)
VALUES (1, '$widgetid','$items', '$stats')");`

Comment: thanks Naveen issue was widgetid was unique and I was copying the value :/ thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
create table newTable like oldTable;

insert into newTable
select * from oldTable
where userid = '';
```

But maybe you really just need to update like Naveen said?

Comment: hey tombom, it needs to be a copy on the SAME table with different ids. not a new table so no create table. I figured it needs to be through a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippets in PHP

```
$upd= (
       "INSERT INTO 
        options (userid, widgetid, items,stats) 
        VALUES (1, '". $widgetid ."' , '". $items ."' , '". $stats ."')
       "
      );
```